# How to run other code when an error occurs?

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I need to automatically log into the site, but sometimes a captcha pops up (not always). I have the code ready to run the captcha solving API. How can I activate it only when captcha appears? After opening the site, I have the code:

```
join = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
join.click()
```

And if a captcha appears instead of the "join" button, then the error `"No such element: Unable to locate element"` pops up.
How can I run the captcha solution code after this error and continue the normal code after solving the captcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a try except block:

```
try:
    join = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
    join.click()
except:
    # Your captcha code.
```

If you know your specific exception you can replace `except:` with `except ExceptionName:`